# Open txt from a list with the vectors of the locations

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list with 4 vectors, and in each one there are the locations of different txt files. Like this

```
ubi <- list(a = c("base1_a1.txt", "base2_a1.txt", ...),
            b = c("base1_a2.txt", "base2_a2.txt", ..., ...)
```

I need to create a list with the dataframes of the open txt and that contains 4 lists and in each list the dataframes of the previous locations.

I tried this, but didn't work

```
dfs_months <- lapply(lapply(ubi, function(ubi) {ubi[[seq_along(ubi)]]}), function(x) {read.table(x, header = T, sep=";", dec = ".")})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
dfs_months <- lapply(ubi , function(x) lapply(x ,
function(y) read.table(y, header = T, sep=";", dec = ".")))
```

Comment: That might be only applied to lists with lengths 4...

Comment: I think OP means list of length 4 , the answer deals with any list of file names.

Comment: His data  was both length 3 and 4, and he didn't explicitly say exclude lengths below 4, so your's answers.